# Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't recognize my active windows 7 partitions

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit doesn't recognize my active windows 7 partitions. When choosing the installation option as something else during USB boot it shows my hard disk, but not all the partions I have. I tried GParted inside Ubuntu and it shows my hard disk as unallocated.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe02de301

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      206848      411647      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          411648   169154841    84371597    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       169156545   976766975   403805215+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       169156608   275140607    52992000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       275142656   296790015    10823680    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       296792064   509788129   106498033    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       509788160   734705663   112458752    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda9       734705664   976766975   121030656    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 3900 MB, 3900702720 bytes
190 heads, 32 sectors/track, 1253 cylinders, total 7618560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          32     7618558     3809263+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```